# Read word symbol list in java using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to read a Word Document in the java using apache poi but whenerver it encounters a Symbol from the MS word Symbol list , it is showing as an empty space in the String . Below is the code I am using

```
WPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
          XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
          List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphs=doc.getParagraphs();
          for(XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph:xwpfParagraphs)
          {
              System.out.println("paragraph");
              System.out.println(xwpfParagraph.getParagraphText());
          }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `xwpfParagraph.getText()` instead?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have tried it still it shows as an empty space